# nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "editsave"] in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
package com.mvc;
import java.util.List;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.mvc.Employee;
import com.mvc.EmployeeDao;

@Controller
public class EmpController {
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao dao;
    
    @RequestMapping("/empform")
    public String showForm(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("command",new Employee());
        return "empform";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("emp")Employee emp) {
        dao.saveEmp(emp);
        return "redirect:/viewemp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/viewemp")
    public String viewemp(Model m) {
        List<Employee> list = dao.getAllEmployees();
        m.addAttribute("list",list);
        return "viewemp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/editemp/{id}") 
    public String edit(@PathVariable int id,Model m) {
        Employee emp = dao.getEmpById(id);
        System.out.println("Emp id is: "+emp.getId());
        System.out.println("name is: "+emp.getName());
        System.out.println("sal is: "+emp.getSalary());
        System.out.println("des : "+emp.getDesignation());
        m.addAttribute("command",emp);
        return "empeditform";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/editsave",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editsave(@ModelAttribute("command") Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("--Inside EditSave method--");
        dao.updateEmp(emp);
        return "redirect:/viewemp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteemp/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        dao.deleteEmp(id);
        return "redirect:/viewemp";
    }
    
}


// View 
<form:form method="post" action="editsave">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">command: ${command.id}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>Salary : </td>    
                <td><form:input path="salary" /></td>  
            </tr>
            
            <tr>    
                <td>Designation :</td>
                <td><form:input path="designation" /></td>  
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

// Error:
Sep 14, 2020 2:31:18 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver resolveException
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "editsave"]
```

after submitting the form I encounter this Error before the Respective Controller called and can't find any solution about this error.
I got 400 bad request On Browser window when submit the form.why it is converting Action attribute "editsave" to Int I dont understand and giving me 400 http-status i search a lot of website but problem is not resolving

Comment: Check the error it probably indicates that yul are invoking the `edit` method instead of the `editsave` method due to a wrongly `action` url in your form (it probably submits to `/editemp/editsave`).

Answer (score 2):

change the path in form tag

```html
<h1>Edit Employee</h1>
<form:form action="/springjdbc/editsave" method="POST">   
    <table>
        <tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```html
<form:form method="post" action="editsave">
```

The URL in the browser will be like:

```
http://localhost:8080/Your Project Name/editemp/editsave
```

It means `editsave`, as a string, will be transferred to the `editemp` method as an ‘int`parameter`{id}`. This is why it said:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int',nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "editsave"]

You had better change:

```html
<form:form method="post" action="editsave">
```

to

```
<form:form method="post" action="/Your Project Name/editsave">
```

Your *Project Name* is the name you gave when you click new "Dynamic web project" in Eclipse.

Comment: While this is effectively the same solution proposed in the previous answer from 2014, I appreciate that you provided a _much_ more detailed explanation of why reader should implement this change. This is a good first answer.